# How to transform character indices to SpaCy token indices?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am using SpaCy to find patterns in texts.
For some patterns such as single words this is straightfoward, and I am happy with the results.
For example,

```
import re
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("Month", [[{"TEXT": "January"}]])

doc = nlp("The date 1 January 2022 can also be written as 1/1/2022.") 

for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc):
    match_id_string = matcher.vocab.strings[match_id]
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(match_id_string, span.text, start, end)
```

will find "January" as the fourth token in `doc` and recognize it as a "Month" pattern.

For patterns that are dates things are a little more complicated.
I use that SpaCy allows to search for patterns that are formulated as regular expressions.
Adding the code

```
matcher.add("Date", [[{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "1/1/2022"}}]])
```

where "1/1/2022" is a (very simple) regular expression,
will find the date "1/1/2022" in the above defined `doc`
and recognize it as a "Date" pattern.
But adding

```
matcher.add("Date", [[{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "1 January 2022"}}]])
```

will not find the date "1 January 2022".
As [explained](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#regex-text) on SpaCy's website
this is because the matcher only matches on single tokens.
The solution provided by SpaCy is to
"match on the `doc.text` with `re.finditer`":

```
for match in re.finditer("1 January 2022", doc.text):
    start, end = match.span()
    span = doc.char_span(start, end)
    print(span.text, start, end)
```

This finds "1 January 2022" as the character range from indices 9 to 23.

However, I would like to put the matches found using `re.finditer`
into the usual SpaCy format of matches,
which is a 3-tuple containing a match ID and the start and end indices of *tokens*
rather than start and end indices of a character range.

**Question:**
How can I transform these character indices to token indices?

Does SpaCy provide a method for doing this?
I guess that would be ideal, but I didn't find one.
Otherwise, are there any other clever tools for doing this?
I could try to make one more or less from scratch,
but that feels like reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get the token indices from the span.

```
for match in re.finditer("1 January 2022", doc.text):
    start, end = match.span()
    span = doc.char_span(start, end)
    
    match = (match_id, span[0].i, span[-1].i + 1)
```

Additionally, if you are trying to match a literal phrase, you can just use the PhraseMatcher, which is already supported by the EntityRuler - you just pass a string as a pattern instead of a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks! And good point about matching literal phrases. I will actually be matching more complex regular expressions that are not literal phrases, but otherwise the PhraseMatcher would have been the way to go.